# Why does GlobalConfiguration.Configure not apply the authorization attribute to the MVC controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.6

I have a asp.net mvc project (.NET 4.6.1) which also has a web api in the same project.

The api folder has got the web api controllers.

The Controllers folder next to the api has got all mvc controllers.

In the App Start folder's FilterConfig.cs there is nothing. In the RouteConfig.cs there is class with RegisterRoutes method which has the route handler:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Matter", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

In Startup.Auth.cs there is cookie based auth code.

In WebApiConfig.cs there is following code:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new MyAPIAuthAttribute());
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

`MyAPIAuthAttribute` is defined in another file. It inherits from `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` and overrides `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` to return a custom message along with 401 status code.

In the global.asax there is following code:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

So it looks like `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` registers the routes for the mvc project. `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` registers the filter and routes for the webapi project.

Issue:
For example - when I enter the webapi controller's GET action method in the browser then it return Unauthorized 401. Where as  when I enter the mvc controller's GET action method then it doesn't perform authorization.

My question is - Why isn't the authorization configuration defined in the global.asax (above methods) applied to both mvc and web api controller actions? Since it is globally configured, I was expecting it to be applicable to all controllers in the project.

I think the solution is to either use [Authorize] or a custom class that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute and place it into the FilterConfig.cs for it to apply to the mvc controlelrs?

Comment: This is an existing project and I have been tasked to add auth to couple of mvc controller actions. I come from .net core background and was expecting an unified experience in asp.net mvc looking at the global registration of mvc and webapi in global.asax. So this is a new learning for me. Is the solution I have given at the end of the question appropriate in asp.net mvc?

Comment: Sure. Try it out. See if it works. If it doesn't, create a [mcve].